# Dúvida VBA - Formulários

Tags: vba

Como fazer a formatação do campo CPF na figura abaixo?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Grato

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 4):

### Máscara de entrada

Na propriedade `InputMask` do seu textBox, inclua a máscara `000.000.000-00`, dessa forma:

```
seuTextBox.InputMask = "000.000.000-00"
```

A máscara pode receber os caracteres:

- **0** - Dígito (0 a 9, entrada obrigatória, os sinais de mais [+] e de menos [?] não são permitidos).
- **9** - Dígito ou espaço (entrada não obrigatória, os sinais de mais e de menos não são permitidos).
- **#** - Dígito ou espaço (entrada não obrigatória; os espaços são exibidos como espaços em branco no modo de edição, mas os espaços em branco serão removidos quando os dados forem salvos; os sinais de mais e de menos são permitidos).
- **L** - Letra (A a Z, entrada obrigatória).
- **?** - Letra (A a Z, entrada opcional).
- **A** - Letra ou dígito (entrada obrigatória).
- **a** - Letra ou dígito (entrada opcional).
- **&** - Qualquer caractere ou um espaço (entrada obrigatória).
- **C** - Qualquer caractere ou um espaço (entrada opcional).

---

### Veja também

Para mais informações, mais opções de caracteres (além dos listados acima) e para encontrar a documentação completa, acesse a [página do MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff821336.aspx).