# Máscara de CPF em VBA

Tags: vba

Como fazer a formatação do campo "CPF" conforme figura abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Taisbevalle jQuery não tem nada a ver com VBA

Comment: @jbueno, coloquei a pergunta errada. Obrigada pelo aviso. Veja essa [Dúvida VBA - Formulários](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183807/51124).

Comment: Ah, tens razão. Votei como duplicata.

Comment: @Agfn1946 Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa, ao invés disso leia o guia [ask] e o faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.